# Can I save result from invoke-restmethod as variable instead of an -outfile in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have a Invoke-Restmethod API script that creates a new mailinglist and returns the following

```
  Code Message                              Result
  ---- -------                              ------                             
  1    Mailing list successfully created    12345678
```

I need the result (ID for the new mailnglist) for the next operation.

I know I can use -outfile to save the result to txt\xml\json and import it using get-contents, but it strikes me as more efficient and clean to just save the result in a variable without having to save an outfile and importing it back in. Is there a way to do this?

My complete code:

```
Invoke-RestMethod $url -Method $method -Headers $headers -Body (ConvertTo-json $body) -ContentType "$outform"
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, yes. Add `-PassThru` switch to your `Invoke-RestMethod` call, and assign the output to a variable as normal.

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod @args -PassThru # when there's "outfile" in args
```

In fact, if you *don't* use `-outfile`, your results should already be available for saving as a variable.

```
$result = Invoke-RestMethod @args # when there's no "outfile" in args
```

EDIT: If you need only one field out of the total result (so you don't need `code`,`message` etc), you can save only the result's `result` field like so:

```
$result = (Invoke-RestMethod @args).result
```

Comment: What does "@args" mean? should I litteraly write args, or is this short for "whatever arguments in your code"? I am very new to powershell so there are probably a lot of basics I have missed. I have edited my post to include my code.

Comment: I wrote that as a short for "whatever is there". So in your case you wrap the entire call to `Invoke-RestMethod` in round brackets and assign to a variable. But, there *is* a syntax `@variable`, that means "get the hashtable "variable" and interpret it as "parameter=value"". Say in your case `$args=@{}; $args["Method"]=$method;...` (fill the rest like this) can be used as a valid input for `@args` syntax.

Comment: Thank you! It almost works, but for some reason, the results variable gives med an incorrect value. When I use write-host $result, I get the result value +1, eg. not 10000 but 10001

Comment: Well, you should look into your REST API specification, probably what's in result is say "next ID" instead of "current ID".